# how to call a pre-trained decoder model in custom loss function in keras?

Tags: keras, loss-function

I trained a auto-encoder model before and saved decoder model. Next, I train a new model that labeled as 'netA', I want to use decoder model in custom loss function. and tried, but I got error, there was my code and error information:

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
   a = decoder(y_pred)
   b = decoder(y_true)
   c  = K.mean(K.square(a-b))
return c
input_feature = 409
output_feature = 256

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu',input_shape=(input_feature,)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))


model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_feature,activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4),loss=custom_loss, metrics = ['mse'])

history = model.fit(x_train_pca_scale, y_train_scale_coding, epochs = 200, batch_size = 32, verbose= 2,validation_data = (x_test_pca_scale, y_test_scale_coding))
```

the error is :

> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>        23 
>        24 model.summary()
>   ---> 25 model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4),loss=custom_loss, metrics = ['mse'])
>        26 #checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/home/lidan/3DFacePrediction/gene.face.autoencoder/gene.face.min.val_loss.hd5', monitor='val_loss',verbose=1,mode='min',save_best_only=True)
>        27
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py
>   in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>        73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
>        74             with get_graph().as_default():
>   ---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
>        76         else:
>        77             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py
>   in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights,
>   sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
>       227         #                   loss_weight_2 * output_2_loss_fn(...) +
>       228         #                   layer losses.
>   --> 229         self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)
>       230 
>       231         # Functions for train, test and predict will
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py
>   in _prepare_total_loss(self, masks)
>       690 
>       691                     output_loss = loss_fn(
>   --> 692                         y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)
>       693 
>       694                 if len(self.outputs) > 1:
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py in
>   **call**(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
>        69         scope_name = 'lambda' if self.name == '' else self.name
>        70         with K.name_scope(scope_name):
>   ---> 71             losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)
>        72             return losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
>        73                 losses, sample_weight, reduction=self.reduction)
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py in
>   call(self, y_true, y_pred)
>       130             Loss values per sample.
>       131         """
>   --> 132         return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
>       133 
>       134     def get_config(self):
>
> in custom_loss(y_true, y_pred)
>         3 def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
>         4     a = decoder(y_pred)
>   ----> 5     b = decoder(y_true)
>         6     c  = K.mean(K.square(a-b))
>         7     return c
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py
>   in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>        73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
>        74             with get_graph().as_default():
>   ---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
>        76         else:
>        77             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, inputs, **kwargs)
>       487             # Actually call the layer,
>       488             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
>   --> 489             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>       490             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
>       491
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py
>   in call(self, inputs, mask)
>       581             return self._output_tensor_cache[cache_key]
>       582         else:
>   --> 583             output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
>       584             return output_tensors
>       585
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py
>   in run_internal_graph(self, inputs, masks)
>       796                         input_shapes = unpack_singleton(
>       797                             [x._keras_shape for x in computed_tensors])
>   --> 798                         shapes = to_list(layer.compute_output_shape(input_shapes))
>       799                         uses_learning_phase = any(
>       800                             [x._uses_learning_phase for x in computed_tensors])
>
> ~/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py
>   in compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
>       915     def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
>       916         assert input_shape and len(input_shape) >= 2
>   --> 917         assert input_shape[-1]
>       918         output_shape = list(input_shape)
>       919         output_shape[-1] = self.units
>
> AssertionError:

I felt confused about the error information,because the decoder model worked well in y_pred and failed in y_true.

Could someone help me solve it or just give me another way to put a saved decoder model in loss function? Thank you very much!

Comment: why do you say 'decoder model worked well in y_pred and failed in y_true'? could you please also add your enc-dec structure and how you create decoder

Comment: Because if I removed `b = decoder(y_true)`  and specified b as constant number, such as 5 in the loss function. the whole code worked well and no error informarion.